# Pass Jinja2 template as html string while rendering using FastAPI?

Tags: html, jinja2, fastapi

My template is as follows:

```
<!-- template1.html -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Item Details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>{{ req }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

To render the template I am using the following code:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()

template = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.get("/list_items")
def home(request: Request):
    return template.TemplateResponse('template1.html',{"req": req})

@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def read_items():
    return """
    <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form action="/list_items">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
          <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
    """
```

But I do not want to use a separate folder with files for a simple template. How do I pass the html text instead of the function `TemplateResponse`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`HTMLResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#html-response). Pass `HTMLResponse` as the parameter `response_class` of your route.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/items", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def read_items():
    return """
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Some HTML in here</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Look ma! HTML!</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
    """
```

You can also override the response directly in your endpoint, by returning it.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/items")
def read_items():
    html_content = """
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Some HTML in here</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Look ma! HTML!</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
    """
    return HTMLResponse(content=html_content, status_code=200)
```

## Update

[`Jinja2Templates.TemplateResponse`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/f6ea760a80d8b109fb6afd1c03e9a33754e6bb5f/starlette/templating.py#L86) expects as `name` parameter a filename that is pointing to the template your would like to return, and which lies in the `Jinja2Templates` directory you defined (e.g., `Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")` ). You can't pass the template contents to its place. Jinja2Templates will attempt to retrieve the file you passed using the directory you defined earlier, see [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/f6ea760a80d8b109fb6afd1c03e9a33754e6bb5f/starlette/templating.py#L97) -> [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/f6ea760a80d8b109fb6afd1c03e9a33754e6bb5f/starlette/templating.py#L83) -> [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/f6ea760a80d8b109fb6afd1c03e9a33754e6bb5f/starlette/templating.py#L65). Hence, what you are asking, it doesn't seem to be natively possible (but, with some hackish stuff maybe doable); however, there is nothing wrong with having a `templates` directory, even for small template files.

Comment: Thank you for your response but how do I pass the `request` argument

Comment: i am sorry i edited my post

Comment: Sorry that was a different code inserted by accident

Comment: It's worth noting that the file loader is set as _a default_ in the jinja2 environment, so you should be able to provide an alternative loader through the `loader` parameter when creating the `Jinja2Templates` object. I'm guessing you could do some hackish stuff by providing the actual template as the name parameter. But instead of doing that, just stick the template in `templates` unless it's a dynamic template adjusted by trusted users.