# How to integrate a basic html file to my FastAPI endpoint?

Tags: python, fastapi

My FastAPI app has a couple of endpoints, but I want to create a new one, which should open a html file with basic details about my application. Is that possible? I'd appreciate any help you can give me.

I tried basic formatting of text, but it has many limitations.

Comment: Please take a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73315502/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70771526/17865804)