# Why does I get 405 Error Method Not Allowed while deploying app to frontend?

Tags: javascript, python, fastapi

That's my user registration endpoint:

```
router = APIRouter(
    prefix='/auth',
    tags=['auth']
)
@router.post('/register', status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def register(db: dp_dependency, 
                   create_user_request: CreateUserRequest):
    create_user_model = User(
        username = create_user_request.username,
        password_hash = get_hashed_password(create_user_request.password),
        email = create_user_request.email,
        last_login_date = datetime.now()
    )

    db.add(create_user_model)
    db.commit()
```

Now while I'm trying to deploy it in a frontend app like that:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const registrationForm = document.getElementById('registrationForm');

    registrationForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
        const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        const email = document.getElementById('email').value;

        fetch('http://localhost:8000/auth/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username: username,
                password: password,
                email: email,
            }),
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Success:', data);
            alert('User registered successfully!');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            alert('Registration failed. Please try again.');
        });
    });
});
```

In my http://localhost:8000/auth/register I'm getting
{"detail":"Method Not Allowed"}
And in fastapi server console:
`INFO:127.0.0.1:52908 - "GET /auth/register HTTP/1.1" 405 Method Not Allowed`
Does someone know how to resolve it?

Comment: error suggests that you run `GET` instead of `POST`

Comment: yes but, in python file I have declared _router.post_ and in js file i declared method as a _'POST'_. I've also checked API by FastAPI swagger and Postman and everything works fine for it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I didn't use GET endpoint, because the browser was waiting for GET first that's how I resolved it.

```
@app.get('/auth/register', status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK, include_in_schema=False)
async def show_register_form():
    return FileResponse('index.html')
```

Comment: You might find the following answers helpful as well: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73315502/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74338314/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70771526/17865804)