# Fastapi - HTMX search

Tags: fastapi, htmx

I'm following a YT video to get the hang on HTMX but the presenter writes in JS, so I've been trying to tag a long in Python.

But I can't get my search on static users to work.

No matter what I've tried it just won't fetch/display the users as I type in the search bar.

I'm thinking it might be the way I try to search and join with my "results" to display.

this is my HTML/HTMX:

```html
<input placeholder="Begin Typing To Search Users" 
       name="search" 
       id="search" 
       type="search" 
       class="border border-gray-600 bg-gray-800 p-2 rounded-lg w-full mb-5"
       hx-post="/search"
       hx-trigger="input changed delay:500ms, search"
       hx-target="#search-result"
       hx-indicator="#Loading...">
```

the backend:

```py
@app.post('/search', response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def search(request: Request, hx_request: Optional[str] = Header(None), 
                 name: str = Form (), email: str = Form(), 
                 search: str = Form()):
    search = search.lower()
    
    data_users = [
        {'name': 'John Doe', 'email': 'john@example.com'},
        {'name': 'Jane Doe', 'email': 'jane@example.com'},
        {'name': 'Alice Smith', 'email': 'alice@example.com'},
        {'name': 'Bob Willams', 'email': 'bob@example.com'},
        {'name': 'Matty', 'email': 'Matty@example.com'}
    ]
    
    if not search:
        print('No Search')
    
    # User search
    search_users = [
        user for user in data_users
        if name.lower() in user['name'].lower()
        or email.lower() in user['email'].lower()
    ]
    
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
        
    # The result i want to present
    search_result_html = "".join(
        f"""
        <tr>
            <td><div class="my-4 p-2">{user['name']}</div></td>
            <td><div class="my-4 p-2">{user['email']}</div></td>
        </tr>
        """
        for user in search_users
    )
    context = {'request': request, 'result': search_result_html}
        
    if hx_request:
        return Response(content=search_result_html, status_code=200)
    else:
        return temp.TemplateResponse('search.html', context),
```

Comment: Have you tried returning an `HTMLResponse` instead, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73315502/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70797993/17865804)? You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70771526/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74994223/17865804) helpful as well

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response, I tried that it didn't make a difference

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly (either from server or web console)? The htmx part looks fine other than htmx-indicator attribute - it should be element id, not the content itself, seems like you have issues with fastapi backend, but you need to provide more debug details (preferably - request and response from the web console).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding this solution

which was exactly what i needed

i removed the

```
search_term = search.lower()
```

don't know why i had that to begin with.

and just did

```
search.lower()
```

then i checked my search input against with the expression under, doe

```
search_results = list(filter(lambda user: user['name'].lower().find(search) != -1 or user['email'].lower().find(search) != -1, data_users))
```