# How to enable CORS in FastAPI for local HTML file loaded via a file:/// URL?

Tags: javascript, python, cors, fastapi, local

I am trying to enable CORS in FastAPI on my localhost with credentials enabled. According to the [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/) we must explicitly set allow_origins in this case:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware, Response

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware, allow_origins=['http://localhost:8000'],
    allow_credentials=True, allow_methods=['*'], allow_headers=['*'])

@app.get('/')
def main():
    return Response('OK', status_code=200)
```

However, when making a request it does fail with

> CORS Missing Allow Origin [Cross-source (cross-origin) request blocked: The same origin policy disallows reading the remote resource at `http://[::1]:8000/create_session/none`. (Reason: CORS header `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` is missing). Status code: 200.]

```js
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/', {credentials: "include"});
```

The client is Firefox with a local file (file://.../main.html) opened.

I already tried all solutions from [How can I enable CORS in FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65635346/23263766). What's wrong?

Edit:
My question is not a duplicate of [How to access FastAPI backend from a different machine/IP on the same local network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75040507/how-to-access-fastapi-backend-from-a-different-machine-ip-on-the-same-local-netw), because the server and the client are on the same (local)host. Nevertheless I tried setting the suggested *--host 0.0.0.0* and the error remains the same.

Also it's not a duplicate of [FastAPI is not returning cookies to React frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73962743/fastapi-is-not-returning-cookies-to-react-frontend), because it suggests setting the CORS origin in the same way as the official docs, which does not work as I described above.

Comment: Hey, according to the doc, your setup is correct. let me try

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/

Comment: If you're opening a `file://` url there won't be any solutions to getting CORS to work - you'll have to load it from `localhost:8000` and not `file://`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp

Comment: I found the issue. It's a simple mistake. However, could you please tell me which FastAPI and Python version are you using?

Comment: If the server runs on `http://localhost:8000`, why are you listing this as an allowed origin in your CORS configuration? Read more about CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: @AsMdHabibullah This is Python 3.10.12 with FastAPI 0.105.0

Comment: @jub0bs Because the client runs on the same machine as the server.

Comment: @Speech-To-Text.Cloud But surely they don't run on the same [Web origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) (perhaps `http://localhost` but with a different port); otherwise, CORS simply wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Speech-To-Text.Cloud In fact, you write: _The client is Firefox with a local file (file://.../main.html) opened._ In that case, the client's origin is `null`, which is different from `http://localhost:8000`.

Comment: @jub0bs I tested with 'null' and it works, thank you. If you turn that into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Hey, have a look "Response" does not exist in this FastAPI version. Even though it exists, but you didn't import it. do fix it first

Comment: from typing import Union
from fastapi import FastAPI, status, Response
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

Comment: # Create a FastAPI instance
app = FastAPI()

# Define origins for CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)
origins = [
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:8080",
]

# Add CORS middleware to the FastAPI app
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

Comment: # Define a root endpoint
@app.get("/")
def main():
    # Option 1: Return a plain Response object with a custom status code
    # return Response({"message": "OK"},)

    # Option 2: Return a plain Response object with a string body and a custom status code
    return Response("OK", status_code=200)

# OR

# Define a root endpoint a different way
@app.get("/", status_code=200)
def main():
    # Return a dictionary as a JSON response with a message
    return {"message": "OK"}

Comment: @Speech-To-Text.Cloud My intent was **not** to encourage you to allow the `null` origin in your CORS configuration, though. Doing so is insecure. For more details, see https://portswigger.net/research/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for-bitcoins-and-bounties

Comment: @jub0bs This is only for testing purposes. It doesn't go live anywhere. But thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't provided the actual [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS) error in your question, it should be specified here for future readers visiting this post. When sending a JavaScript HTTP request to a server, in this case a FastAPI backend, through a local HTML file that has been loaded into the browser via a `file:///` URL—e.g., by dragging-dropping the file into the browser or just double-clicking the file—with the URL in the browser's address bar looking like this:

```
file:///C:/...index.html
```

browsers that apply CORS would output the following errors. If you are using Chrome (or a chromium-based) browser, you would see a `CORS error` (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing error: [`MissingAllowOriginHeader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin)) under the `Status` column in the `Network` tab/section, indicating that the response to the CORS request is missing the required [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header, in order to determine whether or not the resource can be accessed. The error is made more clear by looking at the console, after submitting the request:

> Access to fetch at `'http://localhost:8000/'` **from origin** `'null'`
> has been blocked by CORS policy: No `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`
> header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response
> serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the
> resource with CORS disabled.
>
> GET `http://localhost:8000/` net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)

If you are using FireFox instead, you would see a similar error in the console:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at `http://localhost:8000/`. (Reason: CORS header
> `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` missing).
>
> Status code: 200

The reason for the error(s) raised above is that you are trying to perform a cross-origin request through a script that is running via  a `file:///` URL. In that case, the client's origin is `null`, but you only added `http://localhost:8000` to the allowed origins. Thus, a quick fix would be to add `null` to the `origins` list, e.g., `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null`. In FastAPI, you could do that as shown in the example below (however, it is **not recommended** to do so—see more details below the example).

##### Working Example

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = ['null']  # NOT recommended - see details below
          
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.get('/')
def main():
    return 'ok'
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>Send JS request</h1>
      <button onclick="getData()">Click me</button>
      <script>
         function getData() {
            fetch('http://localhost:8000/')
               .then(resp => resp.json()) // or resp.text(), etc.
               .then(data => {
                  console.log(data);
               })
               .catch(error => {
                  console.error(error);
               });
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

### Note

However, it is **not recommended** doing that, as it is **insecure**. As described in [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin):

> **Note**: [`null` **should not** be used](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-cors-for-developers/#avoid-returning-access-control-allow-origin-null): "It may seem safe to return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "null"`, but the serialization of the
> Origin of any resource that uses a non-hierarchical scheme (such as
> `data:` or `file:`) and sandboxed documents is defined to be `"null"`.
> Many User Agents will grant such documents access to a response with
> an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "null"` header, and any origin can
> create a hostile document with a `"null"` Origin. The `"null"` value
> for the ACAO header **should therefore be avoided**."

Another great article on the risks of using the `null` origin, as well as misconfiguring CORS in general, can be found [here](https://portswigger.net/research/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for-bitcoins-and-bounties).

As explained in several related questions, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8456538/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52919331/17865804), one should rather serve the HTML file(s), e.g., `index.html` above, using a local web server. FastAPI can do that for you as well, using the `HTMLResponse` or even `Jinja2Templates`, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73315502/17865804), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71741617/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74338314/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70771526/17865804). Thus, I would **strongly recommend** having a look at those posts and serve your HTML file(s) through FastAPI, which is pretty straightforward, instead of adding `null` to the `origins`.

Related answers on CORS can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75041731/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I _did_ mention the CORS error in my question, you may want to have a closer look. Also thanks for mentioning the security implications: I use it for testing only and not in production. I may switch to outputting the code as HTMLResponse in the future.

Comment: I meant the complete error message shown in the console (as it would help future readers), not just the `CORS Missing Allow Origin` part. Regardless, glad that the answer helped you understand the security implications of it as well. Indeed, despite the fact that it is used for testing purposes only, I would still **strongly suggest** switching to an `HTMLResponse` or `Jinja2Templates.TemplateResponse` instead - the linked answers provided above would help you on how to do that.

Comment: I did not add it in the first place, because it is localized. I have now added it anyway.

Comment: [English is required for all content on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions); hence, please consider translating it to English.

Comment: I translated the exception message to English.